# How to install nvidia-docker2 on ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: docker

How to install nvidia-docker2 on ubuntu 18.04 ?  What are the specific steps ?

Comment: What do you mean by nvidia-docker2?

Comment: Did you look at the [installation instructions](https://docs.nvidia.com/datacenter/cloud-native/container-toolkit/install-guide.html) at all? A good place to start.

Comment: Thanks very much